# Count number of inquiries received on a given day for a given company where company name may have multiple spellings

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have an export of the 1000 customer inquiries for a given month for multiple companies on worksheet `data`.

B1 through AF1 has numbers 1 through 31 for each day of the month. A2 has our first company name (Cars, Inc.) and A3 has our second company name (Airplanes, Inc.).

I want to know how many inquiries we received for a given company on a given day. This is easy enough with a COUNTIFS formula. The example below would return the number of Cars, Inc. inquiries for the 1st of the month.

```
=COUNTIFS(data!$N:$N,B2,data!$V:$V,"Cars, Inc.")
```

Sample results:
[image]
I'm looking to solve for the Company name being submitted using a variety of names (Used Cars, Old Cars, Cars, Inc.). I know I can do this if I add an additional helper column and leverage a VLOOKUP table but I wanted to see how this could be accomplished with a single formula.

Sample VLOOKUP table:
[image]

Thank you in advance! I've got much to learn in Excel.

Comment: Do you mean the "Cars, Inc" in COUNTIF function instead of the "Names" in VLOOUP table?

Comment: should be doable by substituting the array of Names where you have Company in your formula (probably using the `filter() formula). This should return an array of counts. You can convert the array to a single number by wrapping your formula with `SUM()`

Comment: @Lee There are 4 Company results all of which are Cars, Inc. I'd like a VLOOKUP or something else that can reconcile all of those as being the same company.

@gns100 I'll look into that. I've never used `filter()`. I'll take examples if you've got 'em otherwise I'll dig in tonight!

Used Cars
USED
Old Cars
Cars, Inc.

Comment: Is it fair to assume that you want to sum all names that include e.g., car? Or could it be that there are variations (potential overlaps) that need to be allocated to different names?

Comment: Yes, it can be accomplished.  But you will need to retain your lookup table and may have to use sumproduct rather than countif.